# It's possible to call changePage() inside pagebefore event?

Tags: jquery, event-handling, jquery-mobile, function-calls

I'm working in a file called `action.js` to manage all the actions in my app. In this file I capture the event `pagebeforechange`.

This is a fragment code from my action.js:

```
$(document).bind( "pagebeforechange", function( e, data ) {
    if (typeof data.toPage === 'string') {
        //This is an action
        var urltomatch = data.toPage.match(/action\/(.*)/);
        var action = null;
        if (app.isArray(urltomatch) && urltomatch.length > 0) {
            action = urltomatch[1];
        }

        if (app.isNullOrUndefined(action)) {
            return true;
        }
        switch(action) {
            case 'login':
                //Login action
            case 'logout':
                if (app.logout()) {
                    $.mobile.changePage("pg/static/login");
                }
                e.preventDefault();
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

My problem is when I want to do a `$.changePage` inside the `pagebeforechange` event, because this doesn't work.

Is there any way to do this?

I want to do this to build a function for do forward anywhere

```
function forward(to, options){
    $.mobile.changePage(to, options);
}
```

I just found this way to do that changing the value of `data.toPage`:

```
data.toPage = "pg/static/login";
```

But the problem is that I want to call the function `forward` anywhere, not only in `pagebeforechange` event.